# Positive semidefinite ordering for covariance matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, positive-semidefinite

Suppose that *X* and *Z* are matrices with the same number of rows. Let
$$ D = \left[\begin{array}{cc} X' X & X'Z \\ Z'X & Z'Z \end{array} \right]^{-1} - \left[\begin{array}{cc} (X' X)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right],$$ where all inverses are assumed to exist and the zeros represent zero matrices of suitable dimensions. How can we prove that $D$ is positive semidefinite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U = \left(\begin{matrix} X^{T}X & X^TZ \\ Z^TX & Z^TZ \end{matrix}\right) = \left( \begin{matrix} X^T \\ Z^T\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} X & Z \end{matrix} \right) $ is clearly positive semidefinite and since we are given it is invertible it must be positive definite.

Consequently for any invertible matrix $P$ the matrix $PUP^T$ is also positive definite and in particular for $P=\left( \begin{matrix} I & 0 \\ -Z^TX(X^TX)^{-1} & I \end{matrix} \right)$ the matrix $$PUP^T  = \left( \begin{matrix} X^TX & 0 \\ 0 & Z^TZ - Z^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ\end{matrix}\right)$$ is positive definite and hence both $X^TX$ and $Z^TZ - Z^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ = W$(say) must be symmetric positive definite matrices.

Inverting the above we have $(P^{-1})^{T}   \left(\begin{matrix} X^{T}X & X^TZ \\ Z^TX & Z^TZ \end{matrix}\right)^{-1} P^{-1} = \left( \begin{matrix} (X^TX)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) + \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & W^{-1}\end{matrix}\right). $

Since $P^{-1} = \left( \begin{matrix} I & 0 \\ Z^TX(X^TX)^{-1} & I \end{matrix} \right) $ we also have $(P^{-1})^T  \left( \begin{matrix} (X^TX)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) P^{-1} =  \left( \begin{matrix} (X^TX)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) $.

So we have the identity
$$ (P^{-1})^{T}\left(\left(\begin{matrix} X^{T}X & X^TZ \\ Z^TX & Z^TZ \end{matrix}\right)^{-1} -  \left( \begin{matrix} (X^TX)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) \right) P^{-1} = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & W^{-1}\end{matrix}\right)$$

that is

$$
\left(\begin{matrix} X^{T}X & X^TZ \\ Z^TX & Z^TZ \end{matrix}\right)^{-1} -  \left( \begin{matrix} (X^TX)^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right) = P^T \left( \begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & W^{-1} \end{matrix} \right) P. $$

Since $W$ is symmetric positive definite matrix, so is $W^{-1}$ and the right hand side is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume $Z$ is a column vector.

Let $P_{\perp} = I - X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$. This is the orthogonal projector to the orthogonal complement of column space of $X$ and is idempotent and symmetric.

Let $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ$. This is the vector of coefficients obtained from regressing $Z$ on $X$.

I will assume $Z$ does not lie completely in column space of $X$, so $S^2 = ||P_{\perp}Z||^2 = Z^TP_{\perp}Z = Z^TZ - Z^TX(X^TX)^{-1}X^TZ \neq 0$. Note $S^2$ is the residual sum of squares.

Recall the formula for inverting a partitioned matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
A & B\\
C & D
\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}  = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
A^{-1} + A^{-1}B (D - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1} & -A^{-1}B(D - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}\\
-(D - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}CA^{-1} & (D - CA^{-1}B)^{-1}
\end{matrix}\right).
$$

Applying this formula we get $$ \left(\begin{matrix} X^TX & X^TZ\\ Z^TX & Z^TZ\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}(X^TX)^{-1} +  \dfrac{\hat{\beta}\hat{\beta}^T}{S^2} & -\dfrac{\hat{\beta}}{S^2}\\ \dfrac{-\hat{\beta}^T}{S^2} & \dfrac{1}{S^2}\end{matrix}\right).$$

So $$ D = \left( \begin{matrix} \dfrac{\hat{\beta}\hat{\beta}^T}{S^2} & -\dfrac{\hat{\beta}}{S^2}\\ \dfrac{-\hat{\beta}^T}{S^2} & \dfrac{1}{S^2}\  \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} \dfrac{\hat{\beta}}{S} \\ \dfrac{-1}{S} \end{matrix}\right) \left( \begin{matrix} \dfrac{\hat{\beta}^T}{S} & \dfrac{-1}{S} \end{matrix}\right) $$
and so D is clearly positive semidefinite as it is of the form $uu^T$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - isn't $1/S^2$ a number? In the expression for $$\left(\begin{matrix} X^TX & X^TZ\\ Z^TX & Z^TZ\end{matrix}\right)^{-1}=\left(\begin{matrix}(X^TX)^{-1},$$ what are the sizes of the blocks on the right-hand side?

Comment: I am assuming $X$ is $n \times p$ and $Z$ is $n \times 1$. So the diagonal block sizes are $p \times p$ and $1 \times 1.$

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, this will establish it inductively -- my $Z$ had an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: I have add a newer more general proof which does not make additional assumptions.